# Python pandas read dataframe from custom file format

Tags: pandas, parsing, dataframe

Using Python 3 and pandas 0.19.2

I have a log file formatted this way:

```
[Header1][Header2][Header3][HeaderN]
[=======][=======][=======][=======]
[Value1][Value2][Value3][ValueN]
[AnotherValue1][ValuesCanBeEmpty][][]
...
```

...which is very much like a CSV excepted that each value is surrounded by `[` and `]` and there is no real delimiter.
What would be the most efficient way to load that content into a pandas DataFrame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `][` which has to be escape by `\`. Then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) columns and values and remove row with all `NaN` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""[Header1][Header2][Header3][HeaderN]
[=======][=======][=======][=======]
[Value1][Value2][Value3][ValueN]
[AnotherValue1][ValuesCanBeEmpty][][]"""

#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\]\[", engine='python')
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(['^\[', '\]$'],['',''], regex=True)
df = df.replace(['^\[', '\]$', '=', ''], ['', '', np.nan, np.nan], regex=True)
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print (df)
         Header1           Header2 Header3 HeaderN
1         Value1            Value2  Value3  ValueN
2  AnotherValue1  ValuesCanBeEmpty     NaN     NaN

print (df.columns)
Index(['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'HeaderN'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking into pandas parsers ( https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/io/parsers.py#L494-L646 ) and I wasn't able to subclass anything properly...

Comment: Could you just add `]` to the beginning of every line and `[` to the end of every line? Then there will be no need to replace.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. It's a workaround but not an answer. OP shouldn't have given an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove `]` from the beginning of each line and `[` from the end of each line and then read with the delimiter `][`.

```
s ='''[Header1][Header2][Header3][HeaderN]
[=======][=======][=======][=======]
[Value1][Value2][Value3][ValueN]
[AnotherValue1][ValuesCanBeEmpty][][]'''
f = StringIO(s)

s1 = ''.join([line.lstrip('[').rstrip('\n]') + '\n' for line in f.readlines()])
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1), sep='\]\[', engine='python')
```

Output

```
         Header1           Header2  Header3  HeaderN
0        =======           =======  =======  =======
1         Value1            Value2   Value3   ValueN
2  AnotherValue1  ValuesCanBeEmpty      NaN      NaN
```